# SQLServerException when persisting entity - index is out of range

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm having problems persisting an entity with a @OneToOne relationship with another entity. We've recently upgraded to Java 8 with Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 so I'm sure there's some annotation or configuration that has changed.

**Relevant code**

PermitState.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo", name = "PermitState")
public class PermitState implements Serializable {

private String oid;
private Permit permit;
private Integer invoiced;
private Integer used;
private Integer ordered;
private String permitId;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERMITID")
public Permit getPermit() {
    return permit;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "PERMITID", nullable = true, length = 8,insertable = false,updatable = false)
public String getPermitId() {
    return permitId;
}

... more getters and setters (irrelevant)
```

Permit.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "dbo")
public class Permit {

private String permitid;
private PermitState permitState;


...some more attributes, irrelevant


@Id
@Column(name = "PERMITID", length = 8)
public String getPermitid() {
    return permitid;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy="permit", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public PermitState getPermitState() {
    return permitState;
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [dao.srs.model.PermitState]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3099)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 6 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:709)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1034)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setString(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2835)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2804)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3076)
    ... 78 more
```

As you can see, the PermitState entity has both a relation to Permit (via PERMITID, which is the PK in Permit) AND a field called PermitId, which is supposed to the connected Permit's ID. This doesn't seem to work though, it seems that it's trying to insert all 6 attributes even though Permit shouldn't be inserted into the database. I tried to annotate Permit in PermitState with @Transient, but then I get a AnnotationException:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: dao.srs.model.Permit.permitState, referenced property unknown: dao.srs.model.PermitState.permit
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
Just to clarify, the DB only have 5 fields - OID, PERMITID, INVOICED, USED and ORDERED - which is why I'm thinking its trying to insert the Permit entity as well. The exact same code without modifications worked when we used Java 7, Spring 3, hibernate-annotations 3.3.1.GA and hibernate-entitymanager 3.3.2.GA. We now use Java 8, Spring 4 and Hibernate core+entitymanager+ehcache 4.2.19.

Comment: One more thing I found PERMITID used as column name at two places. In permitState as the PERMITID and also for the mapping as well.

Comment: No, the DB only got 5 field, because Permit shouldn't be persisted. Only the PermitId, which would be derived from Permit.permitid, should be persisted. Also this code worked without flaws before Java/Spring/Hibernate upgrade.

Comment: Permit as an object won't get persisted In your case Permit <---> PermitState which is a bi-directional relationship when you specify @OneToOne (mappedBy) in this case on Permit so it will create an FK mapped with Permit in the PermitState table. Now what is the problem You have specified @ JoinColumn then name is PERMITID and also on the @ ID with @ Column the name is PERMITID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to me, judging from the exception, that you tried @Transient while still having the @OneToOne and @JoinColumn. That does not really make sense, as you tell Hibernate you want to handle it yourself and that it should handle it also.

Also I find it a bit confusing you both have the Permit entity and the permitId in PermitState.  You tell it that you don't want to update permitId, but you still use it as the join column?

I recommend removing the permitId and only have the Permit entity in PermitState. You can still have the getPermitId method if you like, but treat it as an agregate instead.

If all else fails try and log the SQL generated by Hibernate to see what is going on. Perhaps pasting it for us to see.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I agree having both Permit and PermitId seems weird (maintaining OLD code can be so frustrating...). I tried to remove PermitId and only have the Permit entity in PermitState. However, I can't change the database, so I still need the PermitId (which is the Permit entity's PK) to be saved in PermitState. Here's a simple UML diagram that shows how I'm envisioning it http://i.imgur.com/uq9dhNh.png. Any help on how I achieve this?

Comment: I solved it using @OneToOne(mappedBy = "permit") on permitState property in Permit.java and @OneToOne, @JoinColumn(name = "PERMITID") on permit in PermitState.java. See my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. I'm still not entirely sure why this works, but it does:

I removed PermitId (the String property) from PermitState.java, and instead used the PermitId from the Permit entitiy in PermitState.

It looks like this:

Permit.java:

```
private String permitid;
private PermitState permitState;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="permit", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public PermitState getPermitState() {
    return permitState;
}
```

PermitState.java

```
private Permit permit;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PERMITID")
public Permit getPermit() {
    return permit;
}
```

Thanks Martin and Bilbo for your help.